# how to convert Ã©,Ãª,... in database mysql to the normal string é,â,... using php?

Tags: php, mysql, latin1

There are the problems of data in mysql.

Some data store with the string like **(1):**`"hello &amp; hello &#039; hello &egrave; ..."`. And some data store with the string like **(2):**`"hello Ã hello Ã© hello Ãª ..."`.

I can solve the string **(1)** to the normal string, but I don't know how to convert the string **(2)** to the normal string?

**Note** : We can not change the data in the existing database :/
Also the both sample is store in the same table and the charset of the table is latin1!

Comment: Check database/table collation set it to UTF-8

Comment: utf8 the db fields, the web page and the db connection

Comment: @swapnesh : what we need to fix it without any change the database :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hello Ã hello Ã© hello Ãª` probably is UTF-8 interpreted as ISO-8859-1.

You can either change the interpretation, e.g. in a browser set a charset, or convert it to ISO-8859-1 using `utf8_decode()`.

Comment: why this character "Ã" is not converted  ?

Comment: all character Ã©,Ãª,... is converted, except this one "Ã"! you know why?

Comment: I can't imagine what letter that might have been. In UTF-8 an Ã (0xC3) is always followed by a second byte to form a character. Ã<space> (0xC3 0x20) is an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: it's just this character that cannot convert. So i just change it from "Ã" to "à" by using str_replace() :D thanks for help @AndreKR

Comment: Oh, I see. `à` in UTF-8 is `0xC3 0xA0`. `A0` in ISO 8859-1 is the non-breakable space which easily breaks when being copied and pasted for example.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**-

Without changing the DB structure try this  --

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'YOUR_CHARACTER_SET')
```

**OR** try this --

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Check this setting, its all bcoz of table collation

[image]

Comment: That alone wouldn't help because the data would be converted to UTF-8 *again*. He would have to convert it with something like CONVERT(CAST(... as BINARY) USING ...) but he wrote he cannot change the data in the DB.

Comment: @AndreKR yeah just checked in and thx for the info i updated my answer i think this will help him or using header() too may help him in this case

Comment: @swapnesh both solution is not my case, because 1. i can not change the database. 2. i'm convert the text to the image. so no need to put the header. anyway, thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONVERT` as `CONVERT ("hello Ã hello Ã© hello Ãª ...", ascii)` ....